# Linux or Java commands to check JVM parameters

Tags: java, linux, caching, dns

When I login to linux machine and wanted to check the following parameters  from linux command line.

```
networkaddress.cache.ttl(java.security.Security property)
sun.net.inetaddr.ttl
sun.net.InetAddressCachePolicy.get()
java.net.preferIPv4Stack (System property)

Java security manager is enabled or not?
```

All above parameters can be executed from java code.
But i want to know linux commands or java command line to find the values in the above mentioned parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The values of these properties etc are all determined by the way that you run a Java application, or by the application itself itself.  For example:

- `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` depends on whether you run the application with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` or not.

There is a linux command or java command to inquire about these things.
Obviously, you can write a simple Java application that you run to find what the defaults are.  But I think you already know that, and how to do it.

Comment: Yesh , I will  copy the java to calss to my cloud machine and run the java class to find the values.

Comment: Could  you please let me know how to know find the java security manager is enabled or not?

Comment: Call System.getSecurityManager().  (Read the javadoc ...)